# Approach to make UDP server?

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, nio, netty

I am new to Java NIO .

I have a java program which queries servers (different IPs /Ports) iteratively in a loop.
But now i want to send all the packets at once instead of in a loop and then store the data received in the reply packet.

The query consists of only 1 reply packet, no further communication is required.

is this the way to do it - >
Make a datagram Channel ,
send all packets via .send() ,
listen for packets and start new thread to process and store packet data.

number of servers maybe >400 .
Is it better to make 400 threads or 400 datagram channels ???
Also should i use async package instead of NIO .

Would it be easier with Netty etc?

Comment: I would get plain NIO working first. It worth noting that while TCP is reliable, UDP is not. You have to allow for the fact that some packet may not arrive.  For 400 TCP connections I would still use one thread, unless there was a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: servers reply only to UDP. Lost packets are not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough to advise of NIO, but regarding replies handling - better use thread pool and channel pool.

**EDIT - more explanation**

You should have just **one** thread that listens on the port to which the servers reply. Upon receiving a reply, submit a "handle task" to a tasks queue. The next available thread will pull that task and handle it.

So, if you have more replies (=tasks) than available threads, the tasks will wait in the queue. Java has nice thread pool support under [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. These limits are of course configurable.

Basically, the listner thread is performing a minimal operation of creating a handle-task and putting in a queue. If you're afraid of missing replies during that short period then you should configure more listener threads... But I doubt there's a real concern there.

Comment: if i make a thread pool with 50 threads and reply packets received are 51 . What will happen to extra packet?

Comment: @Solution why do you have 50 threads when one thread can receive 51 packats?

Comment: if a packet is received while that one thread is still processing previous packet what will happen ?

Comment: yair, using threadpool is not as simple as you advise. It's hard to imagine why one would want to process all packets concurrently - it means there is no connection between the packets or their sending order. The standard executors in java are probably a wrong idea to pursue. My rule of the thumb is processing synchronously/in-line all messages/packets/etc from the same source.

Comment: @bestsss well it does seem there's no significance to sending order. Any other logical connection between replies can be handled in a different thread(s) than the listening thread. Bottom line - IO handling and business logic should be separated. Designated threads are the workers. Working queue is the hand-off between them.

Comment: I never meant to use the listening thread to carry the logic, just using different pipelines/queues per source. Having absolutely independent UDP packets is quite rare. Thread model has nothing to do w/ the business logic however if 50messages come together and they all require a shared resource, the entire threadpool is stuck.

Comment: @bestsss if you can afford opening 400+ ports and creating 400+ listening threads - then you're right it is more simple to code and maintain. However, if you cannot (which is often the case; don't know about this question though) or you think of scalablity - you have to pool your resources. In these cases, the pool should be fine-tuned to withstand the expected throughput (which may be what you referred as not simple).

Comment: even if you have 400ports you still need a single (or few) threads, not 400. The vanilla executors in java are just not suited for the job, you can have a threadpool and pipelined execution in around 200-250 lines of code.

Comment: i am querying game servers so communication consists of 1 packet only and all servers are independent of each other. I am now trying to make a PacketSenderThread , PacketListenerThread ,PacketProceserThread, QueueThread , DatabaseUpdaterThread . Is it ok ?

Comment: And Packet Send/Receive order doesnot matter. Thanks.

Comment: There shouldn't be a `QueueThread`, just a queue data structure. The `PacketListenerThread` puts the reply data in the queue and the `PacketProcessorThread` removes it and processes it. A `DatabaseUpdaterThread` may exist or not. It is independent of the way replies are received from the network. You're welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use UDP, you can use one thread per server and one port for all of them.  You may want to use a couple of port for different message types.

If you use just one multi-cast & port, any listener will hear all packets from any application to that IP & port.

Comment: is there any existing library / open source code which handles multiple concurrent packets in java . Any sample code will also do .Thanks.

Comment: How many network adapters are you listing to? If you have a 1 GB connection and your packets are 1 KB in size, they won't be closer than 10 micro-seconds apart. Unless you are sending close to 100K/s they will appear to be send at almost random times.

Comment: how long does .receive() method works in datagram channel? 
For eg. if i send a packet with .send() and put a breakpoint...wait for some time... can i still use .receive() succesfully.Thanks.

Comment: UDP packets have some queues in your router and your OS.  When these queues fill up, packets are silently dropped.  I suggest you try debugging your application and see what happens. ;)